# Remove Applications page on MDT 2012 Deployment Summary

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012, mdt-2012, mdt

I am using SCCM 2012 and MDT 2012 for OSD and app deployment.  Because of the nature of how some of the apps need to be detected (and which changes as apps get updated) they show up with a warning sign on the Applications tab of the Deployment Summary.  There is pretty much no way to get them all green check marked (not realistically in our setup anyway) so I would like to get rid of that page so that I don't have to hear about it from my teams as they deploy.  Any help would be appreciated.
MDT Summary screen:
[image]

Applications Installed (the tab I want to remove)
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or two?

Comment: Added screenshots as requested

Comment: I'm still looking for any assistance with this issue, if anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Before going further, if you don't need the "Deployment Complete" window, in the MDT file *CustomSettings.ini* add this line that will not display the final report:

```
[Default]
...
SkipFinalSummary = YES
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Your answer is useful, but I do need the Deployment Complete window, its the easy to recognize marker for my techs that the Task Sequence completed without error.